# Display % of upload done

Tags: java, upload

I have a java applet for uploading files to server.
I want to display the % of data sent but when I use `ObjectOutputStream.write()` it just writes to the buffer, does not wait until the data has actually been sent. How can I achieve this.
Perhaps I need to use thread synchronization or something. Any clues would be most helpful.

Comment: Look for existing code that does this.  Don't write you own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for was actually:

```
setFixedLengthStreamingMode(int contentLength)
```

This prevents any internal buffering allowing me know exactly the amount of data being sent.

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `ObjectOutputStream`. It's for writing serialized Java objects, not for writing raw binary data. It may indeed block the stream. Rather just write directly to the `OutputStream` of the URL connection.

That said, the code looks pretty overcomplicated. Even after re-reading several times and blinking my eyes countless times, I can't get it right. I suggest you to send those files according the `multipart/form-data` encoding with help of [Commons HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/index.html). You can find [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/httpclient/how-to-use-multipart-post-method-for-uploading.html) a basic code example. You just have to modify `Part[] parts` to include all the files. The servlet on the other side can in turn use [Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload) to parse the `multipart/form-data` request.

To calculate the progress, I'd suggest to pick [`CountingOutputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/CountingOutputStream.html) of [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io). Just wrap the `OutputStream` with it and write to it.

**Update:** if you don't like to ship your applet with more 3rd party libraries (which I imagine is reasonable), then have a look at [this code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477449/simple-stream-read-write-question-in-java/2478127#2478127) (and the original question mentioned as 1st link) how to create a `multipart/form-data` body yourself using `URLConnection`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know the code is complicated. I haven't written it myself since I just got this code and am trying to make some new stuff in it. I'll give a try at your examples. By the way, I just wanted to congratulate you on your blog for it helped me a lot with JSF!

Comment: I actually need to use ObjectOutputStream because I'm sending a HashMap before the code I presented here...

Comment: Thank you. Well, that's the nature of `ObjectOutputStream`. It can't send the data byte by byte, it can only send the data in chunks/objects. Either live with it or drop it and go ahead with sending a "normal" HTTP multipart/form-data request.