# Sending binary data using http

Tags: java, http, post

I need to send a binary message which is divided to 2 parts:

1. The first part is 4 bytes and it has some information (say an integer)
2. The second part has an XMLtext stream.

I have never done something like this before, how can I do this?

My code is something like this:

```
public String serverCall(String link, String data){
         HttpURLConnection connection;
         OutputStreamWriter writer = null;

         URL url = null;
         String parameters = data;

         try
         {
             url = new URL(link);
             connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
             connection.setDoOutput(true);
             connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml");
             connection.setRequestMethod("POST");    

             writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
             writer.write(parameters);
             writer.flush();
             writer.close();
          }
          catch(IOException e)
          {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
}
```

How do I set the XML to be 4 bytes and how do I have 4 bytes of text before it?

Comment: please change "binnay" in your title to "binary"

Comment: It sounds like you may want a multipart request? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646194/multipart-file-upload-post-request-from-java

Answer (score 2):

(Info) The HTTP protocol uses method PUT to "transport a file on the server" (instead of POST).

The transport of binary data better not have a content type "text/..." but "application/bin".

You however could send the XML as "text/xml; charset=UTF-8", and use your own header

```
connection.setHeader("MyCode",
    String.format("%02x%02x%02x%02x", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]));
```

If you send all as binary, do not use a Writer (converts bytes to some character encoding), but a Stream (BufferedOutputStream). The XML as:

```
byte[] xmlBytes = xml.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

UTF-8 if there is no other encoding mentioned in `<?xml ...>`.

The `close()` already flushes, so `flush()` is not needed.

Comment: `application/octet-stream` would be a more appropriate content type for arbitrary binary data, would it not?

Comment: @Dev indeed, I personally use that, I love that archaic name; octet=byte.

Answer (score 0):

If the binary portion of your message are mere 4 bytes, percent-encode it and send it as an additional url-parameter. alternatively, add it to the existing xml stream.

the java classes [`Uri`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) and [`URLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) provide the necessary methods.