# Image Upload with Post in Java

Tags: java, post, curl

i am trying to upload an image to imagezilla.net in java. with php using curl it´s no problem..

```
$pvars   = array('file' => "@".$imagePath, 'apikey' => "apikey");
$timeout = 30;
$curl    = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://imagezilla.net/api.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $pvars);
$xml = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
$res = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
```

how is it possible to do this in java?

Comment: Related: [Upload files with java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2469451/1065197)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apache HTTPComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) . It is a bit more complicated than cURL, but, it will do the job (you basically have to fill out a form and POST it).

Comment: only find examples for uploading file but not with additionell parameters like the apikey i need here

Comment: That's not that difficult. There are examples for adding parameters (google POST form, HTTPComponents) and there are other examples for uploading the files. You simply have to combine the two.