# Posting jpeg file as text in Android

Tags: android, string, http, jpeg

I have a photo  (jpeg) format in an Android device. Instead of posting the file as a file  using HTTP I prefer to convert that to a string and post it as string using http  to a spreadsheet. I understand jpeg files are encoded and opening them as string shows funny characters. My question is if I send these characters as string using http,  can I get them back on the other side using a binary file editor and save them as jpeg?

Comment: We do not know what you have in mind with sending as string. The way one usually does this is to base64 encode the bytes content of the jpg file to a string. The receiving side will then base64 decode the string to the original bytes.

Comment: Posting / uploading a JPEG(or any binary)file, character by character might not be a good approach to do so. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20380256/2952723)

Comment: The reason I want to do this, I am sending the data to google drive where sending string doesn't need much configuration while sending files requires using APIs etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you can do is, on client side:

1.Convert image to `byte` array.

```
Path path = yourImageFile.toPath();
byte[] byteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

2.Encode the `byteArray` to Base64 `String`.

```
String encodedString = Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(byteArray);
```

3.That's it, send via http.

I'm not really sure what you mean by a binary file editor, but from server side you can retrieve the image like this (if using `Java`):

```
byte[] decodedByte = decodedBase64.decodeBase64(encodedString);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("newPathToYourImage");
out.write(decodedByte);
out.close();
```