# Is it possible for Google Apps Script to receive a file via HTTP POST?

Tags: java, http, post, file-upload, google-apps-script

I'm a bit new to web development, but I have a question about handling file uploads. I am looking into [uploading files from a Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469451/upload-files-with-java) to a **Google Apps script**.

I understand that Google scripts can receive GET/POST requests as I have indeed tried this before, but how would it handle files?

Answer (score 1):

You can upload files using a form. In uiservices a control does that and in htmlservice is a form. You can debug (from chrome) a gas sample that uploads files and see what I posting to the service

Comment: I'm not after UI. But as a matter of fact, when I looked it up and saw the code snippet for the `FileUpload` class, I managed to understand how it works (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/file-upload). Thanks for the direction tho!