# java open browser and upload file

Tags: java, http, file-upload, browser

I have a java desktop application that launches a browser window to open a URL on my web site.

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(java.net.URI.create("http://www.example.com/?param1=parameter1&param2=parameter2"));
```

I would like to extend this to also upload a file.  I have seen a post on uploading a file and parameters at
[Upload files from Java client to a HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469451/upload-files-from-java-client-to-a-http-server)

That looks very doable.  But I need to get the browser window open for the user to press a few buttons.

Looking for suggestions on a way to do that.

Thanks