# How to upload file and pass other parameters to the web server using DataOutputStream in Android Studio

Tags: java, php, android, android-studio

Using this code I can upload files to the server. but I want to pass some other values to the php code to insert that value to database. but with the code I am using I couldn't make it

Here is the code i wrote for onClickListenter

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v== ivAttachment){

        //on attachment icon click
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v== bUpload){
        final String arippe = "arippe";

        //on upload button Click
        if(selectedFilePath != null){
            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Uploading File...",true);

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                    uploadFile(selectedFilePath, arippe);
                }
            }).start();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is UploadFile function code

```
public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath,  String arippe){

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


    String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
    final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

    if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
        dialog.dismiss();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }else{
        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"arippe\""
                    + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(arippe);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;
    }

}
```

and here is the php code

```
$file_path = "uploads/";
    $a = "areef";
    $b = $_POST['arippe'];


    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    $c = $file_path;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){

    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
    $sql_query = "insert into users(name, user_name, user_pass) values('$a', '$b', '$c')";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_query);
```

When I click upload button null value is posted to user_name

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload files from Java client to a HTTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469451/upload-files-from-java-client-to-a-http-server)

Comment: I recommend you using loopj http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Answer (score 0):

Well...you can use multipart request to upload data...

There are so many ways to upload data on server...
1- By using Volley networking library
https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

2- by using retrofit library
http://square.github.io/retrofit/

Best way is to use Volley networking library..because Google Android recommended to use volley for any network operation.

Simple way is to use HttpUrlConnection class to upload data on server.